# Finding index of the lowest value in array

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I have 3 arrays `@energy, @es_energy and @hb_energy` each of which have been indexed with the same name term `[$k]`.

I want to find the lowest value in `@energy` and then using that index value look for the corresponding values in the other arrays.

Currently I am using `my $n = nmin_by { $energy[$_] } 0 .. $#energy;`

And then `$n` is used to output from the other arrays. However, I don't want to use `nmin_by` as it requires an extra library to download for the software package I am using (loads of admin issues).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What library? Also, what do you mean by "name term"?

Comment: I meant index number !

Comment: I tried copying and pasting the code in but i get this error : Use of uninitialized value in array element at -e line 452.
Can't call method "min_by" without a package or object reference at -e line 452.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [List::Util::reduce](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#reduce)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use List::Util qw(reduce);

my @ary = (12, 3, 1, 23); 

my $min_idx = reduce { $ary[$a] < $ary[$b] ? $a : $b } 0..$#ary; 

say $min_idx;
```

---

Put this in a sub so that the implementation is out of sight while the name clarifies the purpose

```
use Carp;

sub get_min_idx {
   my $ra = shift;
   croak "Sub expects array reference" if ref $ra ne 'ARRAY';
   return reduce { $ra->[$a] < $ra->[$b] ? $a : $b } 0..$#$ra;
}

my $min_idx = get_min_idx(\@ary);
```

Tuck it away in a module and you can also change how it works with minimal intrusion.

The error message can be elaborated (tell to user what *has* been passed, for instance) and checks added; for one, given the numeric `<` comparison the sub needs an array with only numbers.

Syntax clafirication: the index of the last element of an arrayref `$rary` is `$#$rary` (while the index of the last element of an array `@ary` is `$#ary`).

Pick your subroutine name carefully; having a good name helps a lot.

Thanks to [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) for commenting on the need for this.

Comment: Is List::Util part of the standard Perl lib?

Comment: @AlexAMP Yes it is.  If you go to the link that I provided in the answer you'll see that it is "perldoc" -- perl's documentation.  That tells you that it is in "core" (installed with Perl).

Comment: @AlexAMP Good :)  Notice that you can use `reduce` for all kinds of jobs.

Comment: A list of the standard modules can be found in `perlodc perlmodlib` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html

Comment: I think your suggestion is great (I would have written a `for` loop with a state variable) but I really don't like seeing `reduce` in code as it's rarely obvious what it's doing without a few seconds' thought. Perhaps it would be better to write an `nmin_by` wrapper for it?

Comment: Very polished use of `croak`! But I suggest `croak "Sub expects array reference" unless $ra and ref $ra eq 'ARRAY'`

Comment: @Borodin  Thank you for kind words :).   I find that `ref` is happy with `undef` (or empty string) and finds it `ne` to `ARRAY`.  (Do you consider such use as bad practice or implementation dependent, or such?)  The `unless` ... I am a little particular about it: I like it when it clearly selects a case that happens very rarely, `$ok = 1 unless $rare_error`.  Its use here -- to me -- indicates that `ne 'ARRAY'` is "expected" (don't mean literally)

Comment: @zdim: I'm on my commute and can't try it, but I was confident that `ref undef` threw a warning. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Borodin  I did test (v5.10 to v5.16 to v5.27.2), and the docs say "_Returns a non-empty string if EXPR is a reference, the empty string otherwise._"  The logic, I guess, is that it either is a reference or it ain't, including everything.  But this very conversation implies that it should be tested against `undef`.  One of those things -- use a property even if it makes one think, or spell it out even if unnecessary?

Comment: @zdim: If `ref` reliably returns a *defined* value regardless of its parameter then it seems counter-intuitive but my comment was wrong and your original code is correct. I apologise. I have a Perl IDE on this phone but it relies on an internet connection for compilation. That's impossible for the majority of my journey underground, but I do have access to `perldoc` so I have no real excuse!

Comment: @Borodin Heh ... :)  It surely isn't _proper_ English of any kind but it is used in popular culture or even speech here, rather rarely of course. ("_It ain't over till it's over_" comes to mind as an example, and that's pretty mild)

Comment: @Borodin  I had no idea what [distinguished history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ain%27t) the phrase has -- thank you for making me look it up! (I just meant to play with it)